# Orbits of arithmetic subgroups intersection a compact set

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let us suppose we have $G$ a connected reductive group over a number field $F$. Consider $G(\mathbb{A})$ the group over the adeles and $G(\mathbb{Q})$ embedded discretely. For $\gamma \in G(\mathbb{Q})$ we denote by $\mathcal{O}(\gamma)$ the orbit $\gamma$ under conjugation by elements of $G(\mathbb{A})$. My question is the following. If $M$ is a compact subset of $G(\mathbb{A})$, is it true that only finitely many $\mathcal{O}(\gamma)$ have the property that intersection with $M$ is nonempty?

Note: I am interested in the finiteness of the number of orbits with such property, not the $\gamma$'s.

Comment: If $G$ is anisotropic over $\mathbb Q$, it follows from the convergence of the geometric side of the trace formula.

Comment: I am interested in a more general case than anisotropic. The idea is that this result if true may help me define a new trace formula.

Comment: You get finiteness under a wider equivalence: $x\sim y$ iff their semisimple parts in the Jordan decomposition are conjugate. Otherwise, I tink the statement is wrong.

Comment: @user1688 do you have a reference to the statement when the equivalence relation is the semisimple parts?